# Problemas com o instanciamento do cronometro

Tags: java, android

Boa tarde galera, em minha aplicação estou criando um cronometro "simples" mas estou com problema ao executar aplicação. Criei uma class que nele contém dois métodos um de **start** e o outro de **pause** até ai está certo, na minha activity java, instanciei a class e chamei o método no onclick de um botao e o outro onclick chamei o pause.... ao executar minha activity ele me apresenta esse erro...

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Chronometer.setBase(long)' on a null object reference**

Pelo que andei olhando na internet parece que meu método precisa ser do tipo long... mas eu não sei instaciar uma class long, olhei na internet também e não soube resolver, Alguém poderia me ajudar? segue o código abaixo:

class cronometro:

```
package com.allsport.miyonic.allsport.Controller;

import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Chronometer;


/**
 * Created by nathan on 22/06/2017.
 */

public class TempoJogo {

    private View.OnClickListener context;
    private Chronometer reloginho;
    private long milliseconds;

    /*===========Construct==========*/
    public TempoJogo(View.OnClickListener context, Chronometer reloginho, long milliseconds){
        this.context = context;
        this.reloginho = reloginho;
        this.milliseconds = milliseconds;
    }

    public void startJogo(){
        /*definindo o milliseconds em zero para poder armazenar o valor que for pausado do systema */

        milliseconds = 0;
        reloginho.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - milliseconds);
        reloginho.start();
    }

    public void pausarJogo(){
        /* pegar último valor armazenado no milliseconds menos  o valor atual do systema (0)
         retornando o valor atual da activity*/

        milliseconds = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - reloginho.getBase();
        reloginho.stop();
    }
}
```

class activity (SimplesHome):

```
package com.allsport.miyonic.allsport.Activity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.allsport.miyonic.allsport.Controller.TempoJogo;
import com.allsport.miyonic.allsport.Dialog.DialogFaltaAmarela;
import com.allsport.miyonic.allsport.Dialog.DialogFaltaVermelho;
import com.allsport.miyonic.allsport.Dialog.DialogGol;
import com.allsport.miyonic.allsport.Dialog.DialogInformaction;
import com.allsport.miyonic.allsport.Dialog.DialogSair;
import com.allsport.miyonic.allsport.R;
import com.allsport.miyonic.allsport.Controller.TempoTese;

import Base.*;

public class SimplesHome extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton imgButton_play, imgButton_pause, golCasa, golFora, vermlho, amarelo;
    private TempoJogo tempo;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simples);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        golCasa = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.golCasaId);
        golFora = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.golForaId);
        imgButton_play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgButton_play);
        imgButton_pause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgButton_pause);


        golCasa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                contador++;
                valorOne.setText("" + contador);

                Context alerta = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Goooll!";
                int duracao = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast lert = Toast.makeText(alerta, text, duracao);
                lert.show();

                DialogGol golzinho = new DialogGol();
                golzinho.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "golzinho_tag");
            }
        });

        golFora.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                contador1++;
                valorDouble.setText("" + contador1);

                Context gol = getApplication();
                CharSequence texto = "Goooll!";
                int tempo = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast apresentar = Toast.makeText(gol, texto, tempo);
                apresentar.show();

                DialogGol golzinhoTwo = new DialogGol();
                golzinhoTwo.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "golzinhoTow_tag");
            }
        });

        imgButton_play.setEnabled(true);
        imgButton_pause.setEnabled(false);
        golCasa.setEnabled(false);
        golFora.setEnabled(false);

        imgButton_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imgButton_play.setEnabled(false);
                imgButton_pause.setEnabled(true);
                golCasa.setEnabled(true);
                golFora.setEnabled(true);

                tempo.startJogo();
            }
        });

        imgButton_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imgButton_play.setEnabled(true);
                imgButton_pause.setEnabled(false);
                golCasa.setEnabled(false);
                golFora.setEnabled(false);

                tempo.pausarJogo();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Obrigado....

Comment: Em qual linha do código está dando o erro?

Comment: Nesta linha:  `reloginho.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - milliseconds);`

Comment: @Nathan, parece que você nao instanciou a variavel reloginho, pelo código.

Comment: Fiz uma alteração no código

Answer (score 0):

Você não parece ter inicializado esse objeto "reloginho" em lugar nenhum do código, então ao tentar chamar um método em algo nulo, dá o erro que você postou.

Comment: Então o reloginho é um widget que chamei da class SimplesHome (extends SimplesHome), fiz o cast dele (pegando o id) e estou usando na minha class TempoJogo

Comment: OK, mas a classe "TempoJogo" não tem como saber isso.

Comment: ahhh... Como eu faria isso? como fazer a class TempoJogo saber que o reloginho é um widget chronometer?

Comment: Ué, inicializa o reloginho no construtor da TempoJogo (você não parece ter definido um construtor). Também não entendi porque você estendeu essa classe da SimpleHome que é uma Activity.

Comment: A ideia era... como não posso definir o cast do widget na class TempoJogo, pegaria da class SimplesHome e para isso faria um exteds dessa class Activity. Fazendo desta forma é errado?